# RMI connection between computers

Tags: java, rmi

I am new to the RMI side. I am using eclipse ide and iam trying to connect to an another system which is connected over lan
1st i wrote the interface and implemented it in the server class and i executed that in the remote computer and srver executed successfully
2nd i created the same interface and the client in my computer and tried to execute it but i am getting the error 
"connection reused and my localhost computer ip"

Why i am getting this error i have created the interface same in both server and client machine If i am running through command prompt iam getting the output in eclipse i am getting the error

Comment: Please show us a stacktrace.

Comment: You need to start the RMI listener.  Did you do that?

Comment: Sorry it is refused the problem is when iam trying to run the Client program i am getting the error 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RemoteAddition_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

Comment: I checked in the tutorial and  i understood we have to create a jar consisting of the interface and and the server  stub method. But still i am not able to connect. Should the jar file location should be shared???

Answer (score 0):

The class you are missing must be deployed to the client, along with any other application classes it depends on.